# How can I get all errors when executing a command?

Tags: java, process

I'm developing a java program, at a certain point in the program I need to execute some commands and show all the errors returned by that command. But I can only show the first one.

This is my code:

```java
String[] comando = {mql,"-c",cmd};

File errorsFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator2\\Desktop\\errors.txt");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(comando);
pb.redirectError(errorsFile);

Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();

String r = errorsFile.getAbsolutePath();

Path ruta = Paths.get(r);
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

List<String> fileContents = Files.readAllLines(ruta,charset);

if (fileContents.size()>0){
      int cont = 1;
      for(String str : fileContents){

              System.out.println("Error"+cont);
              System.out.println("\t"+str);
              cont++;
      }
}
else{
     //other code
}
```

In this case I know that there are more than one errors, so I expect more than one output but as you can see in the photo I get only one.
[image]

Comment: so ... maybe only one error was thrown?

Comment: In this case i know that there are more than one error thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key here might be that ProcessBuilder's `redirectError(File file)` is actually `redirectError (Redirect.to(file))` .

From Oracle's documentation of ProcessBuilder class:

> This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form redirectError(file) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation redirectError (Redirect.to(file)).

Most example's I have seen use `Redirect.appendTo(File file)` rather than `Redirect.to(file)`. The documentation may explain why.

From Oracle's documentation of ProcessBuilder.Redirect :

> `public static ProcessBuilder.Redirect to(File file)`
> Returns a redirect to write to the specified file. If the specified file exists when the subprocess is started, its previous contents will be discarded.
>
> `public static ProcessBuilder.Redirect appendTo(File file)`
> Returns a redirect to append to the specified file. Each write operation first advances the position to the end of the file and then writes the requested data.

I would try replacing

```
pb.redirectError(errorsFile)
```

with

```
pb.redirectError(Redirect.appendTo(errorsFile))
```

and see if you get more lines that way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you debugged and checked the contents of fileContents?

EDIT: Sorry, it should be a comment, but can't do it yet :(

Comment: Yes i checked it and in the file only apears the last error thrown

Comment: So you're actually saying that the file only has one error (the last one thrown, if i understand it correctly).
If that's the case, then this might actually be a problem with the command "mql" and how it treats errors. Are you sure that all errors area actually redirected to the error output?
Try redirecting the output (redirectOutput method) to another file and check if, maybe, the errors are listed in that file.